# Double value as a negative zero

Tags: c

I have a program example:

```
int main()
{
    double x;
    x=-0.000000;
    if(x<0)
    {
        printf("x is less");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("x is greater");
    }
}
```

Why does the control goes in the first statement - x is less . What is -0.000000?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: Another very useful resource: ￼￼What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic (http://goo.gl/HlpGNC)

Comment: Using what C compiler? http://ideone.com/vi9rU0

Comment: I am very curious which compiler does such 'clever' optimization? Please tell us.

Comment: If that is possible I'd like to see disassembly - or at least want to know compiler name, version + platform.

Comment: This behavior does not reproduce with the code shown.

Answer (score 9):

IEEE 754 defines a standard floating point numbers, which is very commonly used.  You can see its structure [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Formats):

> Finite numbers, which may be either base 2 (binary) or base 10
>   (decimal). Each finite number is described by three integers: s = a
>   sign (zero or one), c = a significand (or 'coefficient'), q = an
>   exponent. The numerical value of a finite number is

```
  (−1)^s × c × bq
```

> where b is the base (2 or 10). For example, if the sign is 1
>   (indicating negative), the significand is 12345, the exponent is −3,
>   and the base is 10, then the value of the number is −12.345.

[image: Double FP number]

So if the fraction is 0, and the sign is 0, you have +0.0.
And if the fraction is 0, and the sign is 1, you have -0.0.

The numbers have the same value, but they differ in the positive/negative check.  This means, for instance, that if:

```
x = +0.0;
y = -0.0;
```

Then you should see:

```
(x -y) == 0
```

However, for x, the OP's code would go with "x is greater", while for y, it would go with "x is less".

**Edit:** [Artur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488700/artur)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19923339/1084) and [Jeffrey Sax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923873/jeffrey-sax)'s comment to this answer clarify that the difference in the test for `x < 0` in the OP's question is actually a compiler optimization, and that actually the test for `x < 0` for both positive and negative `0` should always be `false`.

Comment: Also, in this case it is comparing `double` variable to `int` literal, which plays a part I think.

Comment: @hyde Doesn't make any difference at all. The integer 0 is promoted to double (+0.0).

Comment: @Nathan "but they differ in the positive/negative check." Please explain. Unless you're explicitly looking at the sign bit, all positive/negative checks for +0 and -0 give the same result.

Comment: @JeffreySax: I added a clarification to this.

Answer (score 2):

Negative zero is still zero, so +0 == -0 and -0 < +0 is false. They are two representations of the same value. There are only a few operations for which it makes a difference:

1. 1 / -0 = -infinity, while 1 / +0 = +infinity.
2. sqrt(-0) = -0, while sqrt(+0) = +0

Negative zero can be created in a few different ways:

1. Dividing a positive number by -infinity, or a negative number by +infinity.
2. An operation that produces an underflow on a negative number.

This may seem rather obscure, but there is a good reason for this, mainly to do with making mathematical expressions involving complex numbers consistent. For example, note that the identity `1/√(-z)==-1/√z` is not correct unless you define the square root as I did above.

If you want to know more details, try and find William Kahan's *Branch Cuts for Complex Elementary Functions, or Much Ado About Nothing's Sign Bit* in *The State of the Art in Numerical Analysis* (1987).

Answer (score 2):

Nathan is right but there is one issue though. Usually most of float/double operations are performed by coprocessor. However some compilers try to be clever and instead of letting coprocessor do the comparison (it treats -0.0 and +0.0 the same as 0.0) just assume that since your **x** variable has minus sign it means that it should be treated as negative and optimize your code.

If you would be able to see how assembly output looks like - I bet you'll only see call to:

```
printf("x is less");
```

So it is optimization stuff (bad optimization).

BTW - VC 2008 produces correct output here regardless of optimization level set.

For example - VC optimizes (at full/max optimization level) the code leaving this only:

```
printf("x is grater");
```

I like my compiler more every day ;-)